# it gives null point exception when the list item is clicked

Tags: android, android-fragments

In portrait, it gives null point exceptioin when the list item is clicked but landscape works just fine... In AnotherAcitivity.java Fragment f2 gets null while debugged...

```
package com.example.myfragmentqadvancedel;

import com.example.myfragmentqadvancedel.FragmentA.Communicator;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Communicator{
FragmentA f1;
FragmentB f2;
FragmentManager manager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    manager = getFragmentManager();
    f1=(FragmentA) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment1);
    f1.setCommunicator(this);
}

@Override
public void respond(int index) {
    f2=(FragmentB) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
    if (f2!=null && f2.isVisible()) {
        f2.changeData(index );
    }else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,AnotherActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("index", index);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
}
```

**FragmentA**

```
package com.example.myfragmentqadvancedel;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class FragmentA extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener  {
ListView list;
Communicator communicator;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container,false);

    return view;
}
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    list=(ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.chapters, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

public void setCommunicator(Communicator communicator) {
    this.communicator = communicator;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int i, long arg3) {
    communicator.respond(i);

}

public interface Communicator{
    public void respond(int index);
   }
}
```

**AnotherActivity.java**

```
package com.example.myfragmentqadvancedel;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;

public class AnotherActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_another);

Intent intent = getIntent();
int index=intent.getIntExtra("index", 0);
FragmentB f2= (FragmentB) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
if(f2!=null)   <-- f2 gets null, index gets +ve value as checked in debugger
f2.changeData(index);
  }
}
```

**FragmentB**

```
package com.example.myfragmentqadvancedel;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FragmentB extends Fragment{
TextView text;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container,false);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    text=(TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView1);
}

public void changeData(int index){
    String[] descriptions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.description);
    text.setText(descriptions[index]);
  }
}
```

**logcat**
    05-27 16:40:37.866: E/AndroidRuntime(961): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

```
05-27 16:40:37.866: E/AndroidRuntime(961): java.lang.NullPointerException 

05-27 16:40:37.866: E/AndroidRuntime(961):  at     com.example.myfragmentqadvance.MainActivity.respond(MainActivity.java:26)

05-27 16:40:37.866: E/AndroidRuntime(961):  at     com.example.myfragmentqadvance.Fragment1.onItemClick(Fragment1.java:42)

05-27 16:40:37.866: E/AndroidRuntime(961):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)

05-27 16:40:37.866: E/AndroidRuntime(961):  at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:name="com.example.myfragmentqadvancedel.FragmentA"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**fragment_a.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="#0f0">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**fragment_b.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#00f" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" 
    android:textColor="#fff"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_another.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".AnotherActivity" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment2"
    android:name="com.example.myfragmentqadvancedel.FragmentB"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your interface in Fragment A seems to be Null. Instead of setting the Interface after finding fragment by id, you should use `onAttach(Activity activity)` method. Here you can force your parent Activity to implement this interface. Check out the code below.

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    /* Check if the Activity implemented Callbacks from this Fragment */
    try {
      communicator = (Communicator) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement " + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + "Callbacks");
    }
}
```

Comment: i used onAttach method but still it doesnt work... i dont understand how can Fragment2 be null.

Comment: You should check your Layout XML, make sure that the IDs assigned for the Fragments are correct.

Comment: And if you can share your project through GitHub or something, It can make it easier to find the bug.

Comment: hyy @osayilgan i've kept all xml files abov. i have jst started to learn fragments. Literally all the codes are above.. thanks for your msg btw

Comment: The first thing I saw is the ID for your `FragmentB`'s Layout. In `AnotherActivity` you are trying to inflate `FragmentB` from `activity_another.xml` and it's ID is `android:id="@+id/fragment1"` not fragment2. Here > `FragmentB f2= (FragmentB) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);`

Comment: i code the program again so i made that mistak . Bt dat wasnot prob. since i have it f2 in my orgi prog. Any way i tried several things and when i put that code in onStart rather than onCreate it works, i dont know why?? Thank you the help...

Comment: I just realized that you are inflating your views in onActivityCreated. That's the reason. You need move them all into onCreateView method. That way you don't need to implement it in onStart.

Comment: @beck did you try my suggestion ? I want to know if it works.

Comment: Hello @osayilgan At first i kept them in onCreateView() but the prog. crashes.so i kept them in onActivityCreated. I noticed that when moved into onCreateView, the fragment may try to open before the activity completes so the prog. crashes...

Comment: I don't think it's the way it's supposed to be. You are probably doing something wrong in a minor place. I don't think I can help you like this.

Comment: sorry for that.. i'll check it again and if i find anything wrong i'll msg you. Never mind...

Answer (score 0):

when i keep the code frm onCreate to onStart of AnotherActivity , it works... dont know whats the prob to put them in onCreate

public class AnotherActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_another);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int index=intent.getIntExtra("index", 0);
    FragmentB f2= (FragmentB) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
    if(f2!=null)
        f2.changeData(index);
}
```

}